# Custom method for employee model - backbone.js one test case is failing

Tags: javascript, json, testing, backbone.js, jasmine

Facing issue with the getExperience Method. dont know why im getting that could anyone please help me in this.
Error :
Testing Custom Method in Employee Model Testing getExperience method of Employee Model Checking experience in Employee Model after getExperience method execution FAILED    Expected 0 to be 21.

```js
<!-- Test Case-->

  it('Checking experience in Employee Model after getExperience method execution', function() {
            var current_date = new Date();
            var current_year= current_date.getFullYear();
            var calculated_exp= current_year-1999;
              employee.getExperience(employee.get('year_of_joining'));
              expect(employee.get('experience')).toBe(calculated_exp);
          });
```

```js
var Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({
 //Write your code here
 getExperience: function(experience) {
       var year_of_joining=employee.get('year_of_joining');
        var current_date = new Date();
            var current_year= current_date.getFullYear();
            var calculated_exp= (current_year)-(year_of_joining);
            return calculated_exp;
    }
});
var   employee = new Employee({
        employee_id:1111,
        name:'Sarah Roe',
        year_of_joining:1999,
       address:'ABC Street',
        experience:0
    });
    alert("Experience of "+employee.get("name")+" is "+employee.getExperience(employee.get('year_of_joining'))+" years");;
```

```html
 <!-- Hmtl -->
<html>    
<head>    
</head>    
<body>    
<div id="app"></div



<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="lib/backbone/backbone.js"></script>  
<script  type = "text/javascript"  src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<script>
// JS with example of setting experience value being set third Example
// JavaScript
var Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({
  //Write your code here

  default: {
    employee_id: 1111,
    name: 'Sarah Roe',
    year_of_joining: 1999,
    address: 'ABC Street',
    experience: null
  },
  getExperience: function(year_of_joining) {
    var current_date = new Date();
    var current_year = current_date.getFullYear();
    var calculated_exp = (current_year) - (year_of_joining);

    this.set({
      experience: calculated_exp
    });
    return calculated_exp;
  }

});


var employee = new Employee({
  employee_id: 721,
  name: "Shrikrishna",
  year_of_joining: 1999,
  experience: 22
});
//please add properties and values of Employee model
//employee.set({'experience': employee.get('year_of_joining')}) ;
alert("Experience of " + employee.get("name") + " is " + employee.getExperience(employee.get('year_of_joining')) + " years");
</script>
<div id="container">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: 0

From the question asked by Hacker Rank there are few test cases out of that one generally fails .

which says expected 22 instead of 0 .

So the complete answer is posted here.

So the Answer to the question is

Answer (score 0):

You never set new value for `experience` attribute of your model. As it is for your test to pass you should use:
`expect(employee.getExperience()).toBe(calculated_exp);`

Note the experience argument is never used by your getExperience function.

Or replace:

`employee.getExperience(employee.get('year_of_joining'));`

with:

`employee.set('experience', employee.getExperience());`

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct answer for custom method for employee model in backbonejs:

```js
var Employee = Backbone.Model.extend({
  //Write your code here
 
  getExperience: function(year_of_joining) {
    var current_date = new Date();
    var current_year = current_date.getFullYear();
    var calculated_exp = (current_year) - (year_of_joining);

    this.set({
      experience: calculated_exp
    });
    return calculated_exp;
  }

});


var employee = new Employee({
      employee_id:1111,
        name:'Sarah Roe',
        year_of_joining:1999,
        address:'ABC Street',
        experience:0,   
});
 
alert("Experience of "+employee.get("name")+" is "+employee.getExperience(employee.get('year_of_joining'))+" years");
```

```html
  <!-- Hmtl -->
<html>    
<head>    
</head>    
<body>    
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.4.1/backbone-min.js"></script>  
<script  type = "text/javascript"  src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```